# oozie dataset timezone offset not working

Tags: hadoop, dataset, scheduling, oozie

I have create an Oozie coordinator which is dependent on a data set before starting. As we are in Australia I have set the Timezone offset to Melbourne and the frequency of data set to 10 minutes.

I tired to get the tzoffSet() EL function to return the Australian Timezone offset but the input dataset is still in UTC time.

below is the coordinator's definition

```
 <coordinator-app name="My_Coordinator55"
  frequency="0,10,20,30,40,50 * * * *"
  start="${start_date}" end="${end_date}" timezone="Australia/Sydney"
  xmlns="uri:oozie:coordinator:0.2"
  >
  <controls>
    <execution>FIFO</execution>
  </controls>
  <datasets>
    <dataset name="inputpath" frequency="${coord:minutes(10)}"
             initial-instance="2016-04-08T04:00Z" timezone="Australia/Melbourne">
      <uri-template>${nameNode}/user/hive/warehouse/InputDir${YEAR}${MONTH}${DAY}${HOUR}${MINUTE}</uri-template>
      <done-flag></done-flag>
    </dataset>
  </datasets>
  <input-events>
    <data-in name="inputpath" dataset="inputpath">
      <instance>${coord:current(coord:tzOffset()/10)}</instance>
    </data-in>
  </input-events>
  <action>
    <workflow>
      <app-path>${wf_application_path}</app-path>
      <configuration>
          <property>
            <name>inputpath</name>
            <value>${coord:dataIn('inputpath')}</value>
          </property>
        <property>
          <name>tablename</name>
          <value>Output${coord:formatTime( coord:dateTzOffset(coord:nominalTime(), &quot;Australia/Melbourne&quot;), &#39;yyyyMMddHHmm&#39;)}</value>
        </property>
        <property>
          <name>oozie.use.system.libpath</name>
          <value>True</value>
        </property>
        <property>
          <name>start_date</name>
          <value>2016-04-08T04:00Z</value>
        </property>
        <property>
          <name>end_date</name>
          <value>2016-10-15T23:14Z</value>
        </property>
      </configuration>
   </workflow>
  </action>
</coordinator-app>
```

below is the outcome when I run the coordinator. for nominal time of 2016-04-08 14:00 (Melbourne time) is looking at 2016-04-08 04:00 (-10 hours which is UTC time)  although I have

```
<instance>${coord:current(coord:tzOffset()/10)}</instance>
```

[Scheduled workflows and required inputs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LnXdQ.png)

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured out the answer so just posting the to help the next timezone daylight saving victim of Oozie.

When you define the tzOffset() [ pay attention to the capitalization of letters there is another function with uppercase T which does not work for datasets] function in Oozie it calculates the timezone difference between the dataset and the workflow timezone. so here the EL function was returning 0 difference between Melbourne(AEST TZ) and Melbourne off course!

```
  <instance>${coord:current(coord:tzOffset()/10)}</instance>
```

So the trick is set the timezone to UTC for dataset and the timezone for the coordinator (workflow) to the actual time if you are using this for to automate the daylight saving time difference.

**Note**: I am using this method to help with automating the day light saving time changes. the function in Winter returns -600 and in Summer it returns -660. and the division by 10 is used because the frequency of the dataset is set to 10 minutes.